# What does "operators on a Hilbert space form an algebra" mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, group-theory, definition, representation-theory

I was reading some group theory notes and I am familiar with the concept of a Lie algebra, but I cannot imagine what the following formulation means:

> What is more, not only states, but also the operators come in representations of the
> symmetry group. Clearly, the **operators on a Hilbert space form an algebra**, hence in
> particular a vector space.

Does this refer to the eigenspace of the operator?

Comment: It's an algebra, ie it forms a vector space (you can add and scale operators), and there exists a distributive product on them (performing successive applications of operators on the Hilbert vector).

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_algebra)

Comment: Ah ok thanks thant makes sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments, an *algebra* $(\mathcal A, \circ)$ consists of a vector space $\mathcal A$ and a bilinear operation $\circ:\mathcal A\times \mathcal A \rightarrow \mathcal A$ which provides some notion of vector multiplication.    Examples include $\mathbb R^3$ equipped with the cross product and the space of $2\times 2$ skew-hermitian matrices equipped with the commutator bracket.

If $\mathcal H$ is some Hilbert space, then the bounded linear operators $\mathfrak B(\mathcal H)$ also constitute an algebra, with the multiplication operation being given by composition.  In other words, for $\alpha,\beta\in\mathfrak B(\mathcal H)$ and $\psi\in \mathcal H$,

$$(\alpha \circ \beta)(\psi):= \alpha \big( \beta(\psi)\big)$$